# Как сохранять данные локально если нету подключения к интернету FireBase?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, кэширование, realm-database, транзакции

Записываю тренировку, которая состоит из большого количества данных которые нужно загрузить в Firebase RealTime. Делаю это через транзакцию.

```
trainPush.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            //________анализ
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.DATA).setValue(data);
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.KPW).setValue(kpw);
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.TONNAGE).setValue(tonnage);
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.INTENCITY).setValue(intencity);
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.TIME_TRAIN).setValue(timeTrain);
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.COUNT_ALL_EXERCISE).setValue(countExercise);
            mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.MY_WEIGHT).setValue(weight);
            //________анализ

            //________кардио
            for (int i = 0; i < nameTimeCardio.size(); i++) {
                mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.CARDIO_EX).child(String.valueOf(i)).child(SettingsConstants.NAME).setValue(nameTimeCardio.get(i).getName());
                mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.CARDIO_EX).child(String.valueOf(i)).child(SettingsConstants.TIME).setValue(nameTimeCardio.get(i).getTime());
            }//________кардио

            for (int i = 0; i < hardEx.size(); i++) {
                int[] thisCount = hardEx.getFullCountOneExercise(i);
                float[] thisWeight = hardEx.getFullWeightOneExercise(i);
                mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.HARD_EX).child(String.valueOf(i)).child(SettingsConstants.NAME).setValue(hardEx.getNameOneExercise(i));
                mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.HARD_EX).child(String.valueOf(i)).child(SettingsConstants.REST).setValue(hardEx.getTimerOneExercise(i));
                for (int d = 0; d < SettingsConstants.COUNT_FOR_HARD_EXERCISE; d++) {
                    mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.HARD_EX).child(String.valueOf(i)).child(SettingsConstants.COUNT).child(String.valueOf(d)).setValue(String.valueOf(thisCount[d]));
                    mutableData.child(SettingsConstants.HARD_EX).child(String.valueOf(i)).child(SettingsConstants.WEIGHT).child(String.valueOf(d)).setValue(String.valueOf(thisWeight[d]));
                }
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);

        }
        @Override public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(b == true) {
                updateData();
            }
        }});
```

НО когда нету подключения к интернету или очень маленькая скорость то данные или не записываются или записываются но не полностью!! 
Я хочу сохранять данные локально если подключение к интернету плохое или его нету. И при повторном запуске приложения пробовать опять передать эти данные в Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

[Документация](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?authuser=0) как всегда в помощь.

---

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.orderByValue().limitToLast(4).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
      System.out.println("The " + snapshot.getKey() + " dinosaur's score is " + snapshot.getValue());
    }
});
```

---

```
scoresRef.orderByValue().limitToLast(2).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
        System.out.println("The " + snapshot.getKey() + " dinosaur's score is " + snapshot.getValue());
      }
});
```

Comment: я почитал документацию. Все равно не могу решить проблему. Там написано что транзакции не возобновляются при подключении к интернету, это первое, и мне нужно отслеживать завершилась ли транзакция или нет. Как это сделать? И почему данные записываются не полностью при потере интернета. ведь при транзакции выхода два, или все запишет или ничего. я правильно понимаю?